# Basic Standards of Exporting to XML?

Tags: xml, excel

I'm just writing a small, data gathering application, and I want to export the output to XML.  Is it perfectly find if the output just looks like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<output>
    <data>
        foo
    </data>
    <data>
        foo2
    </data>
    <data>
        foo3
    </data>
    <data>
        foo4
    </data>
</output>
```

Or is there anything special I need to add, for applications like excel to recognize my XML?

Comment: Yes.  Have you read anything about XML files?  Have you talked with the people who will be getting this XML file?  This kind of thing is often defined by a DTD or a XSD schema.  Have you asked about the DTD or the Schema?

Comment: @S.Lott, the people receiving my file will only be concerned that it opens with excel

Comment: CSV rather than XML may be preferred for excel only needs.

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it work?  If it worked, what are you asking?

Comment: @S.Lott, I also asked because I was interested in what the best practice was.

Comment: @bball: Yet, you also said that "only be concerned that it opens with excel".  I don't understand what you're asking.  Is it "Only Excel" or is it "Generally work as an XML document"?  The two are very different.

Comment: @S.Lott:  We use XML here for some applications, but other people need the file to work in excel.  I figured best practice would be helpful for both of those.

Comment: @bball: Are you saying the "only be concerned that it opens with excel" is not true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always include the XML declaration. It defines the XML version and the encoding.
See http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp

Comment: Thanks, I've added this to my example, in case anyone else thinks there is something else I should include.